How do I enable flow control in macOS Terminal?
In Linux, if I do Control-S, it pauses terminal output, and then Control-Q resumes terminal output.
I would like to replicate this behavior in MacOS, but despite trying different combinations of ixon and ixoff, I cannot seem to get Control-S to suspend output.
The experiment:
$ cat
hello world # Type Control S
# Type foobar
# On Linux, no foobar does not print.
# On MacOS, foobar prints.

Terminal settings in Linux
speed 38400 baud; rows 58; columns 218; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc

Terminal settings in MacOS
stty -a
speed 9600 baud; 43 rows; 175 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
        -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho -pendin -nokerninfo
        -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
        -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
        -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
        eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
        min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
        stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;



It looks like the setting I was missing was:
stty -ixany

According to the docs:

If this bit is set, any input character restarts output when output has been suspended with the STOP character. Otherwise, only the START character restarts output.

